# Object Tracking with Local Binary Patterns : Changing size of the detection ROI

Tags: c++, opencv, object, tracking

I am stuck at the follwing situation. I can found the object with the use of Local binary patterns. But how can I change the size of the roi so that I can get the green ROI. I need ideas guyz.

In code I am using a sliding window approach to calculate distances between  the reference windows LBP histogram distance with all possible  windows LBP histograms and draw the ROI around the found candidate window.

[Here is the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xi5f0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a multi-scale detection scheme:

- start from a minimum size of the detecting window
- perform the detection by sliding the window
- scale the window by a factor (e.g. 1.2)
- detect
- etc. until a maximum window size or until the image size

Then, you could:

- retain the location and the scale of the window where the matching distance is minimal and under a threshold.
- or merge/filter the detections that will occur at approximatively the same position but for different scales.

Comment: I am going to implement this thank you for the idea!

Comment: I do implement it but now I cannot decide which to sellect